# Preparing a database for optimized speed

Tags: mysql

I am preparing a single page with search query on an existing database that was handed over to me.

The database is fixed. No insert/edit/update will happen. only search.

There are 160 databases, all have the same structures. the only difference between each database is the language (dialect) of its content. Each database is a translation of the other.

Each database has 3 tables. 2 of these tables are purely for information/reference only. info about the database. Only 1 table will be involved in searching.

This table has 3 columns.

```
index(int11,primary), content(text), contentid(int11)
```

Here is my concern

The values of `index` index column are an ordinal number from 1 onward

`contentid` has unique content but not set as `unique` in database

I am planning to drop `index` column and use `contentid` as the `primary` and set it to `unique`.

will this have performance improvement?

Hundreds users will be using this simultaneously every session and I am on a shared host.

Comment: Why have so many DBs? Can't you just have a language column?

Comment: No, it won't. In this case being that you said there will be no database changes use a sql caching program like memcached and cache your queries. Make sure your tables are properly indexed, and honestly you could move to nosql for a good performance gain too.

Comment: and also, get off shared hosting, spin up a vpn on digital ocean, its way cheaper and you have full control..

Comment: Dropping a single integer field rarely has any performance impact.

Comment: @user3783243 will I get significan't performance when I merge in one DB? each DB has 40K rows.

Comment: 40k is not a lot of rows, even with 160* your only gonna have 10 million rows.

Comment: @Wayne Why do you want to delete the `index` column (not a wise name btw.)? Since the users will search in the `content` column you might want to add a `FULLTEXT` index and use fulltext search on it.

Comment: @Progman yes because not a wise name and I am thinking since `contentid` is also unique and the data will not change, I plan to use that as the primary key instead. also eliminating the "bad name" `index` column. and by the way, user will search for `contentid`, UI will return content when `contentid` gets a hit (expecting single result everytime)